# opencart cant save long information page description

Tags: mysql, opencart

Currently using Opencart 1.5.6.

Making a simple site and need to display quite a lot of text in my information pages but when I try to save my information pages Opencart seems to only save a set number of characters and my "long" description is cut off and lost.

Comment: ...and what does the Opencart documentation say about this? Have you looked?  Please include in your question any research and troubleshooting steps you have already done, as strongly suggested by StackOverflow guidelines.

Comment: tried force inserting my text which is actually text with html tags in to the database and got
Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'description' at row 1
this
so i changed the data type to long text and it works now
but my content bottom wont load now but that's probably a different problem

Answer (score 1):

Change the database field size in the oc_information table, you can also change the datatype to text for long content for your information